# How to check letters from any language , spaces and some special characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have some data that some of the data contain non English letters , So I want to check letters from any language + spaces + some special characters.

The special characters are: `' () - &`

I tried `/^[\p{L} -()']+$/` but it's not working with something like `Castaٌeda` and `word Castaٌeda`

I want the first character to be any language letter , then a combination of all the allowed characters .

The string could be:

- first-second
- first second
- first'second
- first & second
- first&second
- first(second)
- first (second)
- first-second-third
- first second third
- first second third(fourth)
- first-second-third(fourth)
  ..

Comment: Is that in PHP? `'~^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M} ()'&-]*$~u'` will work.See  [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoeO6d/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , Yes PHP , I'm trying :`$pattern = "/^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M} ()'&-]*$/gmu";` `preg_match($Pattern, $location)` , But I get this error `Unknown modifier 'g' `

Comment: Why use `g` if PHP preg functions do not support it? Try `$pattern = "~^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M} ()'&-]*$~u";`. I forgot that there is a `'` inside the pattern, so you may use double quotes to define the string literal correctly.

Comment: I use preg_match_all instead and it works , But it doesn't match this one Word Word (Word)

Comment: Please share what code you have and what you expect. See https://ideone.com/poyjyp - I thought you were validating.

Comment: Also, [my suggestion above works for `Word Word (Word)`](https://regex101.com/r/QoeO6d/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , I used these as examples , Here you are what aren't valid https://ideone.com/Dm5kwx

Comment: ideone.com/Dm5kwx

Comment: I added a dot to the regex (as it was missing on your list, and I see it is required). Also, I see you have a hard space between words, so it makes sense to use `\s` or `\h` instead of a literal space. See [`"~^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M}\h().'&-]*$~u"`](https://regex101.com/r/QoeO6d/6), and the [IDEONE PHP demo](https://ideone.com/PodcRB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the first character to be any language letter, then a combination of all the allowed characters.

You should re-arrange the current regex to require the first char to be a letter, and the character class to follow should be quantified with `*` (zero or more occurrences).

However, there are some things to note:

- You may have hard spaces between the words, so it makes sense to replace the literal space with `\s` or `\h` (and use the `u` modifier in PHP to make them Unicode aware), or add the `\x{00A0}` pattern into the character class to match hard spaces
- You need to escape a hyphen between single chars in the character class to make it match a literal hyphen, else, it creates a range of chars that the pattern can match
- You should add any other allowed chars before the hyphen later, when you need to fine tune the pattern.

So, you may use

```
$pattern = "~^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M}\h().'&-]*$~u";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QoeO6d/6).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
- `[\p{L}\p{M}\h().'&-]*` - zero or more

  - `\p{L}` - letters
  - `\p{M}` - diacritics
  - `\h` - horizontal whitespace
  - `().'&-` - these specific chars
- `$` - an end  of string (better, add `D` modifier, or replace `$` with `\z` to avoid matching before the last `\n`).

See [the PHP demo](https://ideone.com/PodcRB):

```
$arr = ["first-second", "first second", "first'second", "first & second", "first&second", "first(second)", "first (second)", "first-second-third", "first second third", "first second third(fourth)", "first-second-third(fourth)", "word Castaٌeda", "Alfonso Lista (Potia)", "Bacolod-Kalawi (Bacolod-Grande)", "Balindong (Watu)", "President Manuel A. Roxas", "Enrique B. Magalona (Saravia)", "Bacolod-Kalawi (Bacolod-Grande)", "Datu Blah T. Sinsuat", "Don Victoriano Chiongbian (Don Mariano Marcos)", "Bulalacao (San Pedro)", "Hinoba-an (Asia)"];
$pattern = "~^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{M}\h().'&-]*$~u";
foreach ($arr as $s) {
    echo $s;
    if (preg_match($pattern, $s)) {
        echo " => VALID\n";
    } else {
        echo " => INVALID\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
first-second => VALID
first second => VALID
first'second => VALID
first & second => VALID
first&second => VALID
first(second) => VALID
first (second) => VALID
first-second-third => VALID
first second third => VALID
first second third(fourth) => VALID
first-second-third(fourth) => VALID
word Castaٌeda => VALID
Alfonso Lista (Potia) => VALID
Bacolod-Kalawi (Bacolod-Grande) => VALID
Balindong (Watu) => VALID
President Manuel A. Roxas => VALID
Enrique B. Magalona (Saravia) => VALID
Bacolod-Kalawi (Bacolod-Grande) => VALID
Datu Blah T. Sinsuat => VALID
Don Victoriano Chiongbian (Don Mariano Marcos) => VALID
Bulalacao (San Pedro) => VALID
Hinoba-an (Asia) => VALID
```